# Automatic update oracle table column with time stamp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement where I need to update a table column name 'updated_date' on each insertion and update column with time stamp so if there is insert of record then create a row with insertion of time stamp in update_date and if record is updating then I need to update the current time stamp in update_date column. I want to handle it a oracle level using DDL instead of modifying all the queries. Is there an option in oracle for same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look on TRIGGERS at least as your case has a very simple solution (if I understand your requirement properly):

```
create or replace trigger trigger1 
before insert or update on t1 
for each row 
begin
  :new.updated_date := systimestamp;
end;
/
```

this trigger will fire on insert and updates and you will get current timestamp value in both cases - it doesn't matter if you insert record or update it.

if you have another BEFORE trigger for insert or update you can add following code into:

```
if inserting or updating then
  :new.updated_date := systimestamp;
end if;
```

Please, read the documentation for your version of Oracle RDBMS for more use-cases of triggers.

P.S. and DDL is for data definitions changes (alter table, e.g.), not for inserts/updates/deletes which is DML.